# Random module does not randomize

Tags: python

I've encounter a situation that is really a pain in the ass. I was editing a discord bot in python 3.6, but when it came to test the random module, it seems like it's woking, but only in the python shell after running from IDLE.
The problem is that, when the bot is up and running on discord, after typing the randomize command on chat, it only returns once a name from the list and everytime I enter the command does the same thing. It only picks a name from the list, and it displays that everytime untill I restart the bot, when the story loops.

I've attached here some prints to help out understanding my issue. Hope you guys can give me a good advice, I would really appriciate.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random

nume = ["Codrea" ,"Mariusică" ,"Cosmin" ,"Alexandru" ,"Sebică"]
#print(f"Toți: {nume}\n")

idx = random.randint(0, len(nume) - 1)

#print(f"Astăzi stați la fund de sac, fiindcă {nume[idx]} v-a căcat.")

Client = discord.Client() 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!") 

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print("Ce pula mea faceți mă?")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "!random":
    await client.send_message(message.channel, f"Astăzi stați la fund 
    de sac, fiindcă {nume[idx]} v-a căcat.") 

client.run("")
```

SS's: 
[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AVjc.jpg)

As you can see, names are randomized only when code is runing in shell, but not working through the discord command line, which is "!random".

*PS: sorry for the language and excuse me cause It's my second day in python:).

Comment: You create the random value only once.

Comment: Also please, fix your indentation - what is pasted here is not valid Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `on_message` function to run the random number instead of declaring it globally once:

```py
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "!random":
    idx = random.randint(0, len(nume) - 1)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, f"Astăzi stați la fund 
    de sac, fiindcă {nume[idx]} v-a căcat.")
```

When you call `random.randint()` a random number is generated and saved inside the `idx` variable. But only the number is saved and not the instruction to find a random number. This is why you have to call the random function anew each time you need a new random number.

Comment: Ahaa, now I get it, it works fine. So `random.randint()` only save a value into `idx`. Thank you a lot, you saved me from headache :).